How do I grant a script the ability to read certificates in a directory and only that directory without the whole process running as sudo?
I'm building a node.js (18.19.1) web server on Ubuntu 22.04 and using PM2 process manager to daemonize.
The main script requires read and execute access to two certificate files stored in a separate directory. I can't find the right set of permissions to allow the system user I dedicated to this process to access the files without using sudo. When I run it as sudo it works fine but pm2 then shows the process is running as root: pm2 list output
When ran without sudo my server log outputs the following error: EACCESS path/to/certificates/ permission denied. I have recursively assigned the certificate directory 755 and still receive the EACCESS error.
How can I ensure that my script can read the certificates without granting it access to anything else important?
Note: I don't want to move the certificates as I want certbot to be able to access them for renewal, I also tried using symlinks, but still received a "too many levels of symlinks error.
I also tried this approach, but again :permission denied.
Here is the command I am attempting to use to launch the server:

this does not work
sudo -u nodeUser /usr/local/bim/pm2 start myServerCode.mjs

This does, but the process runs as root, which I don't want:
sudo -u nodeUser sudo /usr/local/bim/pm2 start myServerCode.mjs


Thanks in advance.
- A new Linux user

Your "this does not work" and "this does work" examples appear to be identical.

"...access to two security certificate..." Are these just certificates? Certificates are public keys and you could just make them publicly readable. Private keys need to be kept secret.

@larsks fixed, note the extra sudo in example 2. As for your other question. I was following an example I found here. Which shows the server.js file using both Private and Public keyfiles. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Typically a webserver will start as root to bind to port 443, and read certificates - and subsequently drop privileges. Have you read this?
